# How to count the number of occurances of values in a cell based on 2 different critera

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count (or rather to ascribe the number of total orders) of customers based on a) whether they have purchased before, and b) the date of each purchase.

The table also contains all the products ordered in a single order, each in a different line.

Column F is what I'm trying to define (I have filled these numbers in manually and highlighted for clarity).

I am trying to use COUNTIFS:
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B3,$B3,$A$2:$A3,$A3)

[image: screenshot]

However, I cannot make it work properly.

I need it to count only if
a) the entry in column B is the same as the previous entry, and

b)the date entry (column A) is different then the previous entry. Otherwise, column F should return the same value as the previous entry (so that all 'total orders' for the same email with the same date have the same total orders number.

I think I'm likely missing an 'else' statement somewhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "...as the previous entry". Do you mean the entry directly above the current entry? Or in ANY entry above the current entry?

Comment: Total orders should be the same if it's the same email and date (so if the previous total orders is 1, the next line should also be 1 if the date and email are the same). However, if the date changes, and the email stays the same, then total orders would change to 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(B2=B1,IF(A2=A1,D1,D1+1),COUNTIFS(A$2:$A2,A2,B$2:$B2,B2))
```

Tested below.

[image]

In English, the formula checks if emails are equal, then if dates are equal, if so, it grabs value from above. If dates are not equal but emails are it adds one to number from above. If emails are not equal, it starts the count anew with your original `COUNTIFS`. Because it will always generate a 1 for first row, the structure of the `IF` blocks work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you:

```
=COUNT($A2)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,"<>" & $A2,$B$2:$B2,"=" & $B2)
```

[image]

you can add in operators inside ""s and 'concatenate' with an ampersand (&)

This formula will count any entry above the date given, as long as it is a different date and the same email. I know this is what you were *asking* for, but it isn't neccesarily accurate as a count of prior purchases. In order for this to be accurate you should consider a different method for recording multiple product purchases on the same date. Otherwise, just label the column "Qty of prior *products* purchased" as opposed to "Qty of prior *purchases*. :D GL, speak up if you need anything else!

Comment: did you test this against his data set and expected result? Does not work for me.

Comment: :C Yea I made a spreadsheet just like the one in the picture.. sec, I'll recheck my work

Comment: Yea, it's working but @Scott nailed it with his answer, good stuff ;)